# chrome address bar suggestion numbers

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can anyone point me to a way to number the address bar suggestions in Chrome? And then if I press that number the tab will open and I will navigate there.

In other words, each suggestion will have a number next to it and then that means I can just press the number and navigate to that page.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: There's no such API. The closest thing is `chrome.omnibox` but it requires a keyword prefix.

Comment: ok thanks. had to ask.